# Transform list of pyspark rows into pandas data frame through a dictionary

Tags: pandas, lambda, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a list of PySpark sorted rows to a Pandas data frame using dictionary comprehension but only works when explicitly stating the key and value of the desired dictionary.

```
row_list = sorted(data, key=lambda row: row['date'])

future_df = {'key': int(key),
             'date': map(lambda row: row["date"], row_list),
             'col1': map(lambda row: row["col1"], row_list),
             'col2': map(lambda row: row["col2"], row_list)}
```

And then converting it to Pandas with:

```
pd.DataFrame(future_df)
```

This operation is to be found inside the class ForecastByKey invoked by:

```
rdd = df.select('*')
    .rdd \
    .map(lambda row: ((row['key']), row)) \
    .groupByKey() \
    .map(lambda args: spark_ops.run(args[0], args[1]))
```

Up to this point, everything works fine; meaning explicitly indicating the columns inside the dictionary `future_df`.

The problem arises when trying to convert the whole set of columns (700+) with something like:

```
future_df = {'key': int(key),
             'date': map(lambda row: row["date"], row_list)}

for col_ in columns:
    future_df[col_] = map(lambda row: row[col_], row_list)

pd.DataFrame(future_df)
```

Where `columns` contains the name of each coumn passed to the `ForecastByKey` class.

The result of this operation is a data frame with empty or close-to-zero columns.

I am using Python 3.6.10 and PySpark 2.4.5

How is this iteration to be done in order to get a data frame with the right information?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I realized this can be solved with:

```
row_list = sorted(data, key=lambda row: row['date'])

def f(x):
    return map(lambda row: row[x], row_list)

pre_df = {col_: col_ for col_ in self.sdf_cols}

future_df = toolz.valmap(f, pre_df)

future_df['key'] = int(key)
```